# Grails GSP expressions encoded only in production

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to figure out which configuration is causing the behavior that I'm seeing in Grails v4.0.6.

If I have a GSP expression such as `${myMessage}` and myMessage contains html markup, such as `<div class='some-class'>hello world!</div>`, this is rendering as expected when I run locally in dev mode.

However, if I deploy into production mode, Grails is encoding the html markup and thus it does not render as expected. I am sure this is a configuration somewhere, possibly related to the encoding or codecs configs in application.yml, but I don't see anything that specifically differentiates between dev and production mode.

I'll also note that the times I've seen this have all been when the expression is being used inside a template that is rendered from my custom tag library, such as something like this:

```
out << render(template:"bookTemplate",model:"[book: myBook]")
```

where my problematic expression is located inside _bookTemplate.gsp. I cannot say this is the only scenario where this happens.

Comment: Interestingly I encountered the exact same issue after upgrading a Grails 2 app to Grails 5. Some of our front-end components were broken, but only in non-dev enviroments (like Tomcat on TEST/PROD).

Sadly I found your question after I fixed the problem (also by using raw encoding selectively) and yet I still have the question, why does this differ in non-developement environments/profiles?

Very annoying behaviour that I can't find documented anywhere.

Comment: My issue for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75673595/grails-taglib-encoding-different-when-running-on-tomcat-9/75676459#75676459

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.grails.org/4.0.6/guide/single.html#xssPrevention

> By default, Grails plays it safe and escapes all content in ${}
> expressions in GSPs. All the standard GSP tags are also safe by
> default, escaping any relevant attribute values.
>
> So what happens when you want to stop Grails from escaping some
> content? There are valid use cases for putting HTML into the database
> and rendering it as-is, as long as that content is trusted. In such
> cases, you can tell Grails that the content is safe as should be
> rendered raw, i.e. without any escaping:
>
> `<section>${raw(page.content)}</section>`
>
> The raw() method you see here is available from controllers, tag
> libraries and GSP pages.

and later:

> GSP features the ability to automatically HTML encode GSP expressions,
> and as of Grails 2.3 this is the default configuration. The default
> configuration (found in application.yml) for a newly created Grails
> application can be seen below:
>
> ```
>  grails:
>     views:
>         gsp:
>             encoding: UTF-8
>             htmlcodec: xml # use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
>             codecs:
>                 expression: html # escapes values inside ${}
>                 scriptlets: html # escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
>                 taglib: none # escapes output from taglibs
>                 staticparts: none # escapes output from static template parts
> ```
>
> GSP features several codecs that it uses when writing the page to the
> response. The codecs are configured in the codecs block and are
> described below:
>
> ```
> expression - The expression codec is used to encode any code found within ${..} expressions. The default for newly created application is html encoding.
>
> scriptlet - Used for output from GSP scriplets (<% %>, <%= %> blocks). The default for newly created applications is html encoding
>
> taglib - Used to encode output from GSP tag libraries. The default is none for new applications, as typically it is the responsibility of the tag author to define the encoding of a given tag and by specifying none Grails remains backwards compatible with older tag libraries.
>
> staticparts - Used to encode the raw markup output by a GSP page. The default is none.
> ```

Comment: Thank you @Michal_Szulc for the response. I actually did already read that documentation and it does explain why I needed to use raw() to solve my problem. What I'm trying to figure out is why, when running locally in dev mode, I do not need to use raw() but in production mode I do? What configuration says "be more strict in production" if there is one?