# Grails TagLib encoding different when running on Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, grails, character-encoding, gsp

I've recently upgraded a Grails 2 application to Grails 5 and have one outstanding problem before I'm ready to put this into our test environment.

We call the

```
g.render(template: template, model: model)
```

method where the template is just a string reference to a GSP, and the model is a `Map<String, String>` that is used to populate that GSP.

Behaviour differs between local run-app (in IntelliJ IDEA) and Tomcat 9 on Ubuntu, in a way that breaks the view referenced in template.

The crux of the matter is; given the exact same inputs to the `g.render()` method, the outputs differ like:

IntelliJ IDEA run-app:

```
'EUR (MSRP: 85.34, Range from 79.90 - 106.90, Avg.: 88.94)'
```

Tomcat 9:

```
'EUR \u0028MSRP: 85.34\u002c Range from 79.90 - 106.90\u002c Avg.: 88.94\u0029'
```

There is obviously some character encoding issue going on, but I'm not sure how to override the behaviour of Tomcat or the deployed WAR to make `g.render()` consistent with local `grails run-app`.

We already have this config in our Grails 5 YML:

```
    views:
        default:
            codec: none # none, html, base64
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            codecs:
                expression: none
                scriptlet: none
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
```

What could be the reason for this change in behaviour when running under Tomcat?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.

My particular issue is related to RenderTagLib encoding, and the behaviour seems to differ between local/dev execution and other environments (like production) like I found in this other question (unfortunately after I had spent days searching for a solution, ultimately successfully):

[Grails GSP expressions encoded only in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244682/grails-gsp-expressions-encoded-only-in-production)

Anyway, in dev the application worked as expected and

```
g.render(template: template, model: model)
```

worked as expected. However in TEST/PROD environments this same function would return a character stream that was full of escape sequences.

The solution was to call the method like so:

```
g.render(template: template, model: model, encodeAs: 'raw')
```

which gave me the desired behaviour in any environment. Initially I tried this, unsuccessfully:

```
views:
    default:
        codec: none # none, html, base64
    gsp:
        encoding: UTF-8
        codecs:
            taglib: raw
```

Which did fix part of my application, but was too broad a solution and broke other things.

The first example I gave above `g.render(encodeAs: 'raw')` needed to be used selectively.

Again, very annoying that this behaviour changes when non-dev profiles are used. I couldn't find any documentation explaining it either.